Как удалить лишнюю версию postgreSQL?
Я установила версию PostgreSQL 16, но для работы над моим учебным проектом в вузе необходима 15 версия (сказали обязательно,иначе не запустится на сервере кафедры). Я переустановила, теперь pgAdmin выводит следующее при pg_config --version:
(16.0, server 15.6 (Homebrew))
Подскажите, как удалить 16 версию?

В Терминале:
brew uninstall postgresql@16

